# Whats the best way to do a redirect in PHP with a hashtag?

Tags: php, jquery, http-headers

After a successful authentication I send the user to the home page by calling `header`

```
if($success) {
    header('Location: home.php');
    exit();
}
```

Ulitimatley I'd like to use a hashtag as part of the URL so for instance the URL to the user would look like this:

```
mysite/#!home
```

Can I do something like this or is there a better way to redirect them to the home page after a successful login?

Comment: PHP won't get to see the hashtag -- anything after the hash is not sent to the server. You can use it with Javascript to trigger a redirect, but any answers to this question won't have anything to do with PHP.

Comment: Why don't you test it? And keep in mind that the location header requires a full qualified URI, like `http://example.com/home.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sort of hash tag is usually used with what is called, **"addressing"** or **"deep linking"**, a type of javascript page navagation.  What you want is URL Rewriting, which allows you to do things like www.website.com/home

**Deep Linking : http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/**

**Url rewrite:** http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I've looked at addresses with jquery but I'm a bit confused how to use the API with my existing code. Would you be able to provide an example using my current redirect call to home.php?

Comment: home.php loads my menu and all the "home" content in my main div tag id.  I do this so I can just load content into my main div tag based on a users selection. To keep it simple does it make sense to call: header('Location: menu.php?home'); ? Ideally I don't want to show menu.php but instead just "home" in the URL. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Because this :

```
if($success) {
    header('Location: yoursite/#!home');
    exit();
}
```

is not working ?

Comment: is it really that easy? To be honest I haven't tried that. If thats the solution then I guess my question is how do I actually load home.php?

Comment: Mod_rewrite. See Trevor's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass a parameter to the successful page, and fire off some javascript to anchor the user down if that parameter is set:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php if (isset($_GET['val'])) { ?>
        // redirect to the appropriate hash from parameter
        document.location.hash = "<?php echo $_GET['val'] ?>";
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```

This won't give you a clean URL, but its a quick fix if you don't have access to any URL rewriting.